# How to pass some argument and receive a response string from javascript to asp.net page and update the html document

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a drop down list which executes a javascript function (function typechanged(var)) when it is changed. Now I have to pass the var to the server, which should return a menu according to the var string, and then i have to update the div on which the drop down is located, with the new response text received from the server(which itself contains a new dropdown html string) which is Asp.net , I searched for the solution but there were solutions for server controls asp element, while mine is a html dropdown select not a "drag and drop" control element in the page.How am i supposed to do this...?

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call when `typechanged()` is called.

One possible solution would be to include jQuery on your site:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function typechanged(var) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "the_site_only_containing_new_dropdown.html",
    method: "get",
    data: {
      var: var
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#new_dropdown_placeholder").html(data);
    }                
  });
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="new_dropdown_placeholder"></div>
```

You see that the `data`-argument of the `$.ajax`-method provides the `var` to `the_site_only_containing_new_dropdown.html` in the URL (e.g. `the_site_only_containing_new_dropdown.html?var=123`) where you can act on it.

Comment: Is there any way to get the response from the same page, but to identify that this data is send from the ajax then return drop down only else return the whole page html string kind of thing....,Asp.net specific

Comment: @Rajan you could add an URL-parameter to your ajax-request and if its defined, you output only the part which is relevant.